# Handling React animation with horizontal scrolling

Tags: css, animation, reactjs, flexbox

I'm trying to create an horizontally scrolling page navigation with animations using React and React.addons.CSSTransitionGroup. Currently I'm able to do the horizontal scrolling (with flexbox), page opening/closing, animating entering and leaving. But the animation is not exactly what I want.

Take a look at [this example](http://jsfiddle.net/egon/6985qr33/embedded/result/) ([jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/egon/6985qr33/)).

When you click on a buttons on a previous page it currently pushes the pages that are leaving the screen to the right. Although the correct result would be to animate the leaving pages in the same place. I'm not sure how to achieve that effect with CSSTransitionGroup or know whether it is possible with it at all.

```js
function generateId() {
  var r = "";
  var possible = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789";
  for (var i = 0; i < 10; i += 1) {
    r += possible.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * possible.length));
  }
  return r;
}

var PageList = {
  pages: [],
  listener: function(newpages) {},
  open: function(caption, index) {
    if (index != null) {
      this.pages = this.pages.slice(0, index + 1);
    }
    this.pages.push({
      id: generateId(),
      caption: caption,
      width: (150 + Math.random() * 50) | 0
    });
    this.listener(this.pages);
  }
};
PageList.open("Main");

var PageLink = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    var self = this;
    return React.DOM.button({
      className: "pagelink",
      onClick: function() {
        PageList.open(self.props.caption, self.props.pageIndex);
      }
    }, self.props.caption);
  }
});

var Page = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return React.DOM.article({
        className: "page",
        style: {
          width: this.props.page.width + "px"
        }
      },
      React.DOM.h1({}, this.props.page.caption),
      React.createElement(PageLink, {
        caption: "Alpha",
        pageIndex: this.props.index
      }),
      React.createElement(PageLink, {
        caption: "Beta",
        pageIndex: this.props.index
      }),
      React.createElement(PageLink, {
        caption: "Gamma",
        pageIndex: this.props.index
      })
    );
  }
});

var Pages = React.createClass({
  componentDidMount: function() {
    var self = this;
    PageList.listener = function(pages) {
      self.setState({
        pages: pages
      });
    };
  },
  getInitialState: function() {
    return {
      pages: PageList.pages
    };
  },
  render: function() {
    var pages = this.state.pages.map(function(page, index) {
      return React.createElement(Page, {
        key: page.id,
        index: index,
        page: page
      });
    });
    return React.createElement(
      React.addons.CSSTransitionGroup, {
        component: "section",
        className: "pages",
        transitionName: "fall"
      }, pages);
  }
});

React.initializeTouchEvents(true);
React.render(
  React.createElement(Pages),
  document.getElementById("main")
);
```

```css
/* animation */

.fall-enter {
  transform: translate(0, -100%);
  transform: translate3d(0, -100%, 0);
}
.fall-enter.fall-enter-active {
  transform: translate(0, 0);
  transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  transition: transform 1s ease-out;
}
.fall-leave {
  index: -1;
  transform: translate(0, 0);
  transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  transition: transform 1s ease-in;
}
.fall-leave.fall-leave-active {
  transform: translate(0, 100%);
  transform: translate3d(0, 100%, 0);
}
/* other */

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.pagelink {
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 5px 0px;
  width: 100%;
}
.pages {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row;
  overflow-x: scroll;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background: #ddd;
}
.pages:after {
  flex: none;
  -webkit-flex: none;
  display: block;
  content: " ";
  width: 100px;
}
.page {
  flex: none;
  -webkit-flex: none;
  margin: 8px;
  padding: 10px 31px;
  background: #fff;
  overflow: auto;
  box-shadow: 2px 1px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  border-radius: 3px;
}
```

```html
<body id="main">
</body>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/0.12.2/react-with-addons.js"></script>
```

PS: It's fine if it only works with the newest browsers.

Comment: Have you considered using absolute positioning? If not, you'll have to make sure the viewport has a height equal to the largest amount of space to contain two rows of the element in one column.

Comment: Yes, I've considered it. I would like to keep as much styling in the CSS as possible.

Comment: Do you absolutely have to use React? Additionally, what is the desired behavior when the user clicks fast? Should all extra clicks be ignored until the animation is finished, or should they be queued?

Comment: @AndyM - I don't have to use React, but it does solve a lot of my problems with updating the screen and I have already lot of code dependent on it. When the user clicks fast, the animations and pages should overlap where the latest screen is the topmost item. Basically, the max time before user can manipulate the screen is the time it takes to enter and leave the screen.

Comment: Could you give an example of how the animation should look, I could probably come up with something but am not sure how you want it to look.

Comment: Something like this http://jsfiddle.net/egon/ge8ycrha/embedded/result/ (but with a better easing function, e.g. quadratic).

Comment: And where is scroll in your example? Simple event-driven animation, no scroll at all. Misleading title.

Comment: @Green the horizontal scroll appears if you open multiple of them. It's more obvious in a smaller window.

Answer (score 12):

### Problem

To get the vertical lineup of pages that you're looking for, we're going to have to change the HTML to add an extra layer. This extra layer will be a vertical channel that the `article`s slide up and down in. Right now, new ones are just being pushed to the side because there is no parent layer to contain them.

Second problem is that all the HTML is created dynamically by React. Trying to go in and change a library/plugin is not a good idea, so I tried to create the effect you're going for with jQuery instead.

### Possible Solution

**HTML Structure**

First thing I did was sketch up a desired layout. We need three layers inside the overall parent:

```
Parent
    Cell
        Innercell (doubles in height to contain two articles)
            Article
```

The dotted line in the sketch is the `Innercell`, the Page rectangles are the `Articles`

[image]

**CSS**

For the most part, I'm using your original styling. The main difference is that in the extra layers between the `cell` and `article`. The `cell` keeps it's height fixed at `100%`, then the `innercell` gets `height:200%`. It's also positioned absolutely, with `bottom:0`. This is important, because it means the extra spacing is above the parent instead of below. We also make sure that the article itself is positioned absolutely, with `bottom:0`. This places it in the bottom half of the `innercell`.

**JS**

First thing to do here is to figure out the order we want things to happen. There are three possible routes we can go when a button is clicked.

1. If a rightmost button is clicked, we want to add a new cell, then slide in an article.
2. If a second-to-rightmost button is clicked, we just want to slide in a new article.
3. If any other button is clicked, we want to slide in a new article in the cell to the right, and all further right cells should slide down with no replacements.

[image]

Inside the the `change article` circle, we need to:

1 Create new `article` from template, insert all variable data, and place it in the empty space in the top of the `innercell`.

2 We need to slide the `innercell` down.

3 After the animation is done, we need to remove the previous `article` and reset the `innercell`

### Final Code

```js
var cellTemplate = '<cell data-col="DATACOL"><innercell><article></article></innercell></cell>';
var innerTemplate = '<article class="new"><innerarticle><h1>TITLE</h1><button>Alpha</button><button>Beta</button><button>Gamma</button></innerarticle></article>';
var numCells = 2;
var animating = 0;

$('body').on('click', 'article button', function(event){
    if (!animating) {
        var currentCell = parseInt($(this).parent().parent().parent().parent().attr('data-col'));
        var title = $(this).text();
        if (currentCell == numCells) {
            addCell(title);
        } else if (currentCell == numCells - 1) {
            changeArticle(title,numCells);
        } else {
            removeExtraCells(title,currentCell);
        }
    }
});

function removeExtraCells(title,currentCell) {
    var tempCurrentCell = currentCell;
    changeArticle(title,tempCurrentCell+1);
    while (tempCurrentCell < numCells) {
        tempCurrentCell++;
        deleteArticle(title,tempCurrentCell+1);
    }
    numCells = currentCell+1;
}

function addCell(title){
    numCells++
    var html = cellTemplate.replace('DATACOL',numCells);
    $('section').append(html);
    changeArticle(title,numCells);
}

function changeArticle(title,changingCol) {
    var cell = $('cell[data-col="'+changingCol+'"] innercell');
    var html = innerTemplate.replace('TITLE', title).replace('DATACOL', numCells - 1);
    cell.prepend(html);
    triggerAnimation(cell);
}

function deleteArticle(title,changingCol) {
    var cell = $('cell[data-col="'+changingCol+'"] innercell');
    var html = '<article></article>';
    cell.prepend(html).addClass('deleting');
    triggerAnimation(cell);
}

function triggerAnimation(cell) {
    cell.addClass('animating');
    window.setTimeout(function(event){
        cell.css('bottom','-100%');
        animating = 1;
    },50);
}

$('body').on('webkitTransitionEnd otransitionend oTransitionEnd msTransitionEnd transitionend', 'innercell', function(event){
    if ( $(this).hasClass('deleting') ) {
        $(this).parent().remove();
    } else {
        $(this).children('article:last-child').remove();
        $(this).children('article.new').removeClass('new');
        $(this).removeClass('animating');
        $(this).css('bottom','0');
    }
    animating = 0;
});
```

```css
/* other */
 * {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

section {
    display: flex;
    flex-flow:row;
    overflow-x: scroll;
    overflow-y: hidden;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    background: #ddd;
}

cell {
    flex: none;
    -webkit-flex: none;
    display:block;
    height:100%;
    float:left;
    position:relative;
    width:166px;
}
innercell {
    display:block;
    height:200%;
    width:100%;
    position:absolute;
    left:0;
    bottom:0;
}
.animating {
    transition: bottom 1s ease-out;
}
article {
    display:block;
    padding:8px;
    height:50%;
    position:absolute;
    left:0;
    bottom:0;
}
article.new {
    bottom:auto;
    top:0;
}
innerarticle {
    display:block;
    padding: 10px 31px;
    background: #fff;
    overflow: auto;
    box-shadow: 2px 1px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    border-radius: 3px;
    height:100%;
}

innerarticle button {
    padding: 5px;
    margin: 5px 0px;
    width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section>
    <cell data-col="1">
        <innercell>
            <article>
                <innerarticle>
                    <h1>Main</h1>
                    <button>Alpha</button>
                    <button>Beta</button>
                    <button>Gamma</button>
                </innerarticle>
            </article>
        </innercell>
    </cell>
    <cell data-col="2">
        <innercell>
            <article>
                <innerarticle>
                    <h1>Alpha</h1>
                    <button>Alpha</button>
                    <button>Beta</button>
                    <button>Gamma</button>
                </innerarticle>
            </article>
        </innercell>
    </cell>
</section>
```

**Notes**

I did end up adding a fourth layer, which I called `innerarticle`. This was because you had an `8px` margin on your `article`. With two `article`s on top of each other vertically, the `margin` collapses and doesn't stack. Be adding an `innerarticle` and then giving the `article` a `padding:8px`, I could make sure it stacks.

Also, you may have noticed that I'm using a lot of custom element names. I do that because it works and it makes it easy for you to understand what's doing on. You can feel free to change them all to `<div class="INSERTCURRENTELEMENT">`

Comment: Very nice answer, well explained! And the outcome is pretty damn smooth. +1 for this very good answer.

Comment: Nice answer. But, doing it with vanilla JS is pretty easy, I'm having trouble with integrating that part with React. Basically I'm not quite sure how to interact with React system. (Also fast clicks don't do anything, i.e. imagine if an user misclicks the button, he would have to wait until the page appears, in the meantime some of the input from user might have gotten lost as well.)

Comment: I was going off of your comment response of "I don't have to use React". If you still are trying to, then obviously the JS portion of this answer doesn't work. The HTML/CSS part does though, so the only question is, can you get React to output an extra layer.

Comment: I followed that up with "... but it does solve a lot of my problems with updating the screen and I have already lot of code dependent on it.", this means solves N different problems instead. I guess React can have extra layers, but I haven't quite figured out how things are wired inside. I'm guessing there is some nice way fixing the position from the left when the div is entering, let it flex when it's in position and then fix the left position when it's leaving... but I'm not sure how to do it properly.

Comment: I think we can do this! So right now, you are creating a class for the page. We need to just create a new class for the cell, which calls the page. The tricky part will be in having the buttons move the page and not the cell.

Comment: I've gotten it to the point where it's spitting out the right HTML structure, and I've updated the CSS accordingly. I can't get the numbering of the columns to stay put though. We need to give each a number so that on button click we can decide what to do, but it updates the data attribute each time I click a button, for all cells. http://jsfiddle.net/6985qr33/7/ Hopefully that Fiddle can point you in the right direction.

Comment: I'll give the bounty to you for the effort, although I haven't yet solved my problem.

Comment: I appreciate that. Did you take a look at the updated Fiddle I listed? If you can shed some light on why it updates the data-cell each button click, I might be able to get it closer to working.

Answer (score 2):

Came up with an easy solution by adding this to the css:

```
.fall-enter.fall-enter-active {
    position: absolute;
    height: 97%;
    margin-top: -5px;
}
.fall-enter.fall-enter-active, .fall-leave.fall-leave-active {
    transition: transform 1s ease-in;
}
```

Working example:
http://jsfiddle.net/6985qr33/5/

Have fun

Comment: This approach seems to have a lot of glitching. Especially when you click fast on the items.

Comment: Well, that's a javascript issue, first you need to stop pressing a button tell the first button move is done, second when you add a new section it needs to have the css classes before it's added, not after added.
That's what make the glitch you see.